# Sitewide 301 Code is Not Redirecting All URLs

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

Good day everyone, I did a 301 redirect from old-domain to new-domain but I noticed from Google search console that some urls where still pointing to the old-domain. I had thought placing that 301 code will redirect all the URLs to the new domain. Please is there something I am not getting right.

I have place the follwoing code in the htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-domain\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.old-domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new-domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: The code you have shown _does_ redirect all URLs (assuming, you don't have anything before this, that would handle certain URLs differently.) _"but I noticed from Google search console that some urls where still pointing to the old-domain"_ - maybe Google has no re-visited those URL then, since you made the change.

Comment: I tested those URLs and indeed they were still pointing to the old domain

Comment: You'll need to give us some proper examples here then - just "some" and "those", doesn't help us get clarity on what the issue is.

Comment: I believe I have given all the necessary details, if theirs any other specific detail, off course I can provide it. In fact I just noticed my redirects are not working well. When I enter the old URL it takes me to the new URL which is perfect. However, when I visit specific URLs in the old-domain it doesn't redirect.

Comment: There should be no significant difference between directly "entering" a URL, and requesting it by following a link. What causes your problem, can not be determined by the information we have so far.

Comment: Is this _all_ your .htaccess file contains? If not, then please show it in context. Are both domains pointing to the same folder on the same server, or different locations?

Comment: Thanks for your time. Anyway, I tried using chatGPT and he actually fixed the problem. The first code I pasted above was from chatGPT, I said it didn't work and he suggested pasting a simpler "Redirect 301 / http://new-domain.com/" and it fixed the problem. Now all the pages from old-url are redirecting to the corresponding new-url. Once again, thank you for your time.

Comment: @Emmanuel If `Redirect` works then that implies the two domains are pointing to different servers and the `RewriteCond` directives in your original rule were not required. (Although there's really no difference between the two rules, unless `old-domain.com` or `www.old-domain.com` were not actually the hostname being requested?) However, that still doesn't explain why some URLs were redirected and others weren't. Sounds like you had a caching issue?! OR, you had additional/overriding `.htaccess` files in directories that prevented the redirect (mod_rewrite is not inherited by default)?